# Passing multiple scripts to shell over ssh

Tags: shell, ssh, files, cat

I have a somewhat lengthy script which sources other scripts to include the functions there. I'd like to execute this script remotely via ssh.

Now I thought to make one script file of it (without sourcing it) and then let it execute remotely via ssh.

For example the idea was something like this, unfortunately it does not work:

```
$ ssh user@host < $(cat dep1.sh dep2.sh main.sh)
```

whereas when it is a single file (I merged it before) does work:

```
$ ssh user@host < complete_main_script.sh
```

Any ideas how I would overcome the issue, i.e. make one script file of the three above and send it as a whole via `ssh`?

Comment: Yeah, ok. It's as simple as that

    `cat dep1.sh dep2.sh main.sh | ssh user@host bash -s`

Ok, well, Mr. Obvious is done here... ;)

Comment: to send file with ssh it's a lot eaiser to use `scp` if enable on your server

Comment: @Kiwy OP is not transferring the file as such, rather executing commands therein.

Comment: @peterph I missunderstand sorry.

Comment: if you find the answer please add it and accept it after 24h

Answer (score 2):

`$(command)` is (as the generalized syntax suggests) command substitution - you can think of it as a placeholder for the verbatim output of the command. Hence:

```
$ ssh user@host < $(cat dep1.sh dep2.sh main.sh)
```

Stands for something like:

```sh
$ ssh user@host < "#!/bin/sh
rest your dep1.sh script goes here
#!/bin/sh
rest of your dep2.sh script goes here
...
"
```